# Creating a .bat file to copy the latest file from a network drive and change its name and extension

Tags: batch-file

I have the following in a `.bat`. I am trying to pull the most recent file (as the file name changes each time a new file is generated) from a network drive and copy it to a folder on my desktop changing the name so I can hit it from an outside DB. Unfortunately I am relatively new with `.bat` files and cannot figure out how to pull the latest file instead of the defined file below. I will turn this around and put it into a task scheduler to pull the file every thirty minutes.

```
copy \\fipr01\SNAP\P161201135302673.tmp C:\Users\ddtacopy\Desktop\AutoCopy\SNAP.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dir` to get a list of files sorted by age, take the newest file and then copy it:

```
pushd "\\fipr01\SNAP"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /O:D /T:C "*.tmp"
') do (
    set "NEWEST=%%F"
)
copy /Y "%NEWEST%" "C:\Users\ddtacopy\Desktop\AutoCopy\SNAP.txt"
popd
```

How does it work?

- `pushd` creates a temporary drive letter that points to the given network path and changes to that; this is done because many batch commands do not support network paths;
- `dir /B /O:B /T:C` returns a list of files `*.tmp` in the current directory, with the newest item last; `/T:C` tells `dir` to sort by the creation date; omit that if you want to use the modification date;
- the `for /F` loop around `dir` reads its output and enumerates all the items; for each iteration it assigns the currently iterated item to variable `NEWSET` the `set`; the variable value is overwritten each time, so since the newest item is listed as last, `NEWEST` contains that one finally;
- at that point the retrieved item is copied; the `/Y` tells the `copy` command to overwrite an already existing target file without asking; if you want a prompt to appear, change it to `/-Y`;
- `popd` cleans up the temporary drive letter created by `pushd` and returns to the former directory;